# Pushing into array gives unexpected result

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, javascript-objects

The code snippet below returns unexpected (at least for me) results.

```js
var input = [['one','two'],['three','four']];
    var doc = {};
    var output1 = [], output2 = [];
    input.forEach(function(x){
        doc.firstValue = x[0];
        doc.secondValue = x[1];
        output1.push({firstValue:x[0],secondValue:x[1]});
        output2.push(doc);
        
    })

$('#output1').html(JSON.stringify(output1));
$('#output2').html(JSON.stringify(output2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
output1 is:
<div id='output1'></div>
output2 is:
<div id='output2'></div>
```

The questions are:
1) why output1 doesn't look similar to output2 (while their creation is quite similar)?
2) is there a way to push into array like array.push(obj) (the way output2 is filled) and getting the result like output1 (all the values from initial array would be there)?

Comment: Your question is very unclear about your intentions. Can you please provide the output?

Comment: @ndugger Run the code snippet to view the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) why output1 doesn't look similar to output2 (while their creation is quite similar)?

This has to do with [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) in JavaScript.

Your `output2` array contains two *references* to the `doc` object. These references all point to the *same* instance of `doc`.

So by the time your assignment is all done and you're printing the contents of `output2`, you realize that it is just printing the values of `doc`, which is

```
{
   "firstValue":"three",
   "secondValue":"four"
}
```

> 2) is there a way to push into array like array.push(obj) (the way output2 is filled) and getting the result like output1 (all the values from initial array would be there)?

The simplest way to do this is create a new instance of `doc` each time you want to use it to avoid closure:

```
var output1 = [], output2 = [];
input.forEach(function(x){
    // Declare and define `doc` here to get unique references.
    var doc = {};
    doc.firstValue = x[0];
    doc.secondValue = x[1];
    output1.push({firstValue:x[0],secondValue:x[1]});
    output2.push(doc); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
var input = [['one','two'],['three','four']];
    var doc = {};
    var output1 = [], output2 = [];
    input.forEach(function(x){
        doc = {}; //this is the added line
        doc.firstValue = x[0];
        doc.secondValue = x[1];
        output1.push({firstValue:x[0],secondValue:x[1]});
        output2.push(doc);
        
    })

$('#output1').html(JSON.stringify(output1));
$('#output2').html(JSON.stringify(output2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
output1 is:
<div id='output1'></div>
output2 is:
<div id='output2'></div>
```

You should create a new `doc object` each iteration...You were referencing the same object so it would have the most recent values in it...